# Initialise empty data frame of same structure as another

Tags: r, dataframe

my R code reads data from a csv file. This data has headers and is stored in the data.frame mydata. The headers come from the csv file.

I would like to scale the data to within the [0,1] range and thus doing create another, empty, data.frame called scaled. I then loop through each column and divide by the maximum allowed value, I assume the minimum value is zero.

```
foreach(i = 1:ncol(mydata)) %do% {
    if (i == 1){
        maxval <-100  # Max depth = 100
    }
    else{
        maxval <- max(mydata[,i],na.rm=TRUE)
    }
    scaled[,i] <- mydata[,i] / maxval
}
```

How do I create the empty scaled data.frame with the same headers and structure as mydata?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'empty scaled'? Empty means no data, 'scaled' implied you want the data to be scaled, i.e. non-empty.

Comment: the dataframe will be called scaled.the data frame will initially be empty. I will fill it column by column using the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

```
col1 <- 100:102
col2 <- 200:202
col3 <- 300:302

df <- cbind(col1,col2,col3)

firstrow = df[,1]/100 # first scaled by 100
scaled <- apply(df, 2, function(col) {col = col / max(col)})
scaled[,1]=firstrow
```

which gives

```
scaled

>   scaled
     col1      col2      col3
[1,] 1.00 0.9900990 0.9933775
[2,] 1.01 0.9950495 0.9966887
[3,] 1.02 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the immediate problem that I'm having